# Is it possible to use express js with an MS Access database?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to use a Microsoft Access database (.accdb) as the back-end for a express js application? because i tried different package for connecting that but is not supporting. Is there any ways to connect ms access db with express rest api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use this package. 
>   [nuintun/node-adodb](https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb)

Example of usage:

```
'use strict';

const ADODB = require('node-adodb');
const connection = ADODB.open('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=node-adodb.mdb;');

connection
    .execute('INSERT INTO Users(UserName, UserSex, UserAge) VALUES ("Newton", "Male", 25)')
    .then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: { Error: Spawn C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cscript.exe error
    at ChildProcess.child.on.exitCode (C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\node-adodb\lib\spawn.js:120:37)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
  process:
   { code: -2147467259,
     message:
      'Unrecognized database format \'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Aawsoft\\MobileApp\\android_app\\accessdb.accdb\'.' },
  exitCode: 0 }

Comment: I thought your DB is .mdb!
this package support .mdb database only.

Did you use the following package?
this package will support .accdb databases.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/adonis-adodb

Answer (score 0):

You can try Node-ADODB package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-adodb

**Update**

Looks like you will host your application in Windows environment in Production. You can try using "ActiveXObject" available with package https://www.npmjs.com/package/winax

```
/* Declare Database Setup Options Here
************************************************/
var dbOptions = {
  dbPath: "sample-people.accdb",
  dbUserID: "",
  dbPassword: ""
};
/* MS Access API
 ************************************************/
var MSAccess = function(dbOptions) {
  this.dbOptions = dbOptions;
  this.myConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  this.connStr = "";
  this.sessionStr = "";
  this.connOption;
  var providers = ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'],
    connError = [];
};
```

Reference: https://rtmccormick.com/2015/11/21/connect-to-ms-access-database-with-javascript-hta-app/

Comment: { Error: Spawn C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cscript.exe error
    at ChildProcess.child.on.exitCode (C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\node-adodb\lib\spawn.js:120:37)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
  **process:
   { code: -2147467259,
     message:
      'Unrecognized database format \'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Aawsoft\\MobileApp\\android_app\\accessdb.accdb\'.' },
  exitCode: 0 }**

Comment: I have updated my answer with ActiveXObject approach. This might help you to resolve the issue.